# Problems with log4j2 > 2.12 and maven assembly

Tags: java, maven, log4j2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have created a simple java application to debug my problem but i am still blocked.
I create a jar with maven assembly but i have this error at startup:

```
D:\Workspace_java11\testlog4j\target>java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml -jar testlog4j-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for 'Default' at 'null' in 'null'
```

Here is my maven configuration:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>testlog4j</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.2</version>
            </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.3.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <mainClass>testlog4j.Tester</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                       <manifestEntries>
                           <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                       </manifestEntries>
                   </archive>
                   <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                   <descriptorRefs>
                       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                   </descriptorRefs>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>make-assembly</id>
                       <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>single</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Here is my java code:

```
package testlog4j;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Tester {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Tester.class);
            
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("test log");
    }
}
```

Here is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The weird thing is that it works perfectly with log4j dependencies < 2.13 but it fails when i upgrade to 2.13 or 2.14. I have tested both java 8 and java 11 for the same results.

Any idea about what is wrong here?

Edit:

If it can help, here is the output using -Dlog4j2.debug:

```
D:\Workspace_java11\testlog4j\target>java -Dlog4j2.debug=true -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml -jar testlog4j-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock does not support precise timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0,012922 seconds to load 23 plugins from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 2 plugins
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=Default, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3cef309d]...
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=Default] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3cef309d) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 2 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@51cdd8a
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for 'Default' at 'null' in 'null'
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=Default, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3cef309d] started OK.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopping LoggerContext[name=Default, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3cef309d]
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopping LoggerContext[name=Default, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3cef309d]...
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=Default'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=Default,component=StatusLogger'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=Default,component=ContextSelector'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=Default,component=Loggers,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=Default,component=Appenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=Default,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=Default,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=Default,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@13a57a3b...
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger OutputStream closed
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@13a57a3b OK
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped LoggerContext[name=Default, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3cef309d] with status true
```

Comment: 2.13 adds some compatibility with log4j 1 config files. Perhaps you have a log4j.properties or log4j.xml file on your classpath somewhere.

Comment: Looking at log4j debug logs, it seems to be linked to Converter plugins.
I can see 2 Converter plugins when using log4j 2.13 libs, i had 44 Converter plugins when using log4j 2.12 libs.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52923153/516433) is for the `maven-shade-plugin`, but i _think_ still applies here.  looks like its some sort of build-time cache on the configuration.