# Log4J ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier

Tags: java, maven, log4j, pom.xml, log4j2

I am getting the following errors on deployment of my JAR file.
 `ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern. ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level] ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern. ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger] ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern. ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg] ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern. ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n] ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.`

I understand from reading around on here that this is probably an issue caused by the Log4j2Plugins.dat file. However unlike other posters here I'm not using the Maven shade plugin.

This is my pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <quickfixj-core.version>2.3.1</quickfixj-core.version>
        <aws-java-sdk-kinesis.version>1.12.429</aws-java-sdk-kinesis.version>
        <gson.version>2.10.1</gson.version>
        <quickfixj-messages-fix44.version>2.3.1</quickfixj-messages-fix44.version>
        <ssm.version>2.20.38</ssm.version>
        <log4j-api.version>2.21.1</log4j-api.version>
        <amazon-kinesis-producer>0.15.6</amazon-kinesis-producer>
        <jaxb-api.version>2.3.1</jaxb-api.version>
        <json.version>20230227</json.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.6.0</postgresql.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
            <artifactId>quickfixj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${quickfixj-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
            <artifactId>quickfixj-messages-fix44</artifactId>
            <version>${quickfixj-messages-fix44.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ssm</artifactId>
            <version>${ssm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-producer</artifactId>
            <version>${amazon-kinesis-producer}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>[placeholder]-${project.version}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>[placeholder]</finalName>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>[placeholder]</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

After building the JAR file I tried manually removing the Log4j2Plugins.dat file and this worked however this is not ideal and not something I'd like to do everytime.
Is there a way to prevent these errors from happening? Or if necessary is there a way to stop the Log4j2Plugins.dat file being created in my JAR when I do a maven install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log4J2 dynamic appender doesn't work with maven-shade-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75996306/log4j2-dynamic-appender-doesnt-work-with-maven-shade-plugin)

Comment: Unfortunately no. As mentioned above I'm not using the maven-shade-plugin.

Comment: this issue looks exactly the same as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033792/log4j2-error-statuslogger-unrecognized-conversion-specifier

Comment: Can you run you application with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true`? The details of plugin loading will be on the standard error of the application. Remark: remove `Log4j2Plugins.dat` is never a solution. It is like cutting off one's hand to force him to write with the other one.